# ADAL register application by rest api

Tags: rest, azure, adal, azure-monitoring

I couldn't find it anywhere but was wondering if there is a rest api way that allows to programatically register an application (besides the documented ones (powershell,CLI and by portal). I have an app that needs to access to azure monitor to retrieve some metrics and didn't want the clients to have to register the app by themselves. So it would be something like this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-rest-api-walkthrough
but that I could use in javascript for example.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that the PowerShell sample in the above document works is because Azure PowerShell is registered as an Active Directory application already. At some point, your application will have to be added manually by the customer, since Active Directory APIs can't be executed by a user role.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [New Azure AD application doesn't work until updated through management portal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34811057/new-azure-ad-application-doesnt-work-until-updated-through-management-portal) for the steps necessary to create an application via the Azure AD graph API.

Comment: Thanks, it gives me a general idea, still can't find the js library to work in the same way you work it with c#

Comment: There is AdalJS (https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js). I don't know whether it has feature parity with the ADAL for .net library.

Comment: Thank you, was checking it, it helps in later development, but not really for this, thanks anyway!