# How to register new applications in Azure Active Directory programmatically

Tags: azure, automation, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

Right now this is how I register a new App in Azure Active Directory.

1. Go to the Azure Portal
2. Go to **Azure Active Directory**
3. Click on **App registrations**
4. Click on **Add**
5. Select a **Name**, **Application Type** and **Sign-on URL**
6. Set the **Required Permissions**
7. Set a **Key**

Is there a way that I could do this programmatically? What I am looking for is to do above steps and then return the ApplicationId and the Key (or secret).

**Background**
I have a Web Application with a form that receives an Application name and I want in the Controller of the web app do all the logic. Lastly the controller should return the AppId and Secret generated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add application to Azure AD programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684821/how-to-add-application-to-azure-ad-programmatically)

Comment: Take a look here for a previous answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684821/how-to-add-application-to-azure-ad-programmatically

Comment: Yeah, I saw that one and took a look to the code in this repo https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-GraphAPI-DotNet but I wasn't able to figure out how the Application gets registered from there.

Comment: That sample does NOT explicitly do what you want, but it does set up a framework for an application to get an access token, and query the Graph API. From that point, it is on you to update the sample to then create an application.

Comment: Oh gotcha... that makes sense then :)

Comment: You can check out the code in the questions and answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34723767/create-application-in-azure-active-directory-using-graph-api-fails and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34811057/new-azure-ad-application-doesnt-work-until-updated-through-management-portal/37652942#37652942, that will help you along the way to create the application and service principal etc. required.